# Web site deployment - WCF services in an external DLL

Tags: .net, wcf, web-config, inversion-of-control, wcf-binding

I've an N-Tier web site solution (MVC3-based), where all the components are registered via an IoC container (i.e., the Web project doesn't have references to anything but Interfaces and Models).

One of the projects in the solution needs to work with external WCF services. These WCF requests are contained in this project only, and no other project in the solution needs to be aware of that.

However, when I want to run the web site, I still need to make sure that all the **WCF bindings and endpoints** are present in the **web.config** of the site.

My question is, is it possible to contain all this configuration in the assembly that actually works with the services, so that the Web project could remain blissfully unaware of them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We need to put all the configuration entries in the web.config/app.config of the application that runs.

To keep web application unaware about the services, you can either

- Put all the host, binding, endpoint etc. details in code rather than configuration file. Of course this will reduce the configurability for your application.
- Keep all the service related configuration in separate file and reference that file in web.config.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking along the lines of having a separate services.config file. I was wondering if there's a better (more Magic-y) way to do this somehow with IoC.

Comment: Another way I can think of is to load the dll using service in separate AppDomain. Then, framework will read it's configuration file. If you are using .Net 4.0, check Managed Extensibility Framework.